# Rails form No Method Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to put a simple form together, but I keep getting a no method error whenever I insert a form field into the html.

What's wrong here?

**The Error:**

```
undefined method `name' for #<Upload id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
```

**new.html.erb**

```
<h1>Uploads#new</h1>
<p>Find me in app/views/uploads/new.html.erb</p>

<% form_for :upload, :url => uploads_path do |f| %>
<p>
    Name: <%= f.text_field :name %>
</p>
<p><%= submit_tag "Create Upload" %></p>
<% end %>
```

**upload.rb**

```
class Upload < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :tasks


end
```

**uploads_controller.rb**

```
class UploadsController < ApplicationController
def index
@uploads = Upload.find(:all)
end

def new
@upload = Upload.new
end

def create
@upload = Upload.new(params[:project])
if @upload.save
    flash[:notice] = "Film successfully uploaded"
    redirect_to uploads_path
else
    render :action => 'new'
end
end
end
```

Comment: `has_many :tasks`. Is there a tasks.rb file/class?

Answer (score 1):

From looking at the error, your upload model does not appear to have a name attribute. If you've added this, the maybe you have forgotten to migrate you database?

Comment: that's definitely not it. any other ideas?

Comment: @Adam appears to be right to me. Unless you are using a strange select query somewhere and renaming the name attribute but it doesn't look like it.